# Scroll down TableView in Swift that include many JSON's pages

Tags: swift

guys. I need to scroll my TableView and load data from some JSON's pages. I did this for only one page, but I don't know how to do this for multiple pages. This is API http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=world&page=2&apikey=eae75c46

This API has property "TotalResult", so I can get this and divided by 10. In this case 7180/10, so I have 718 of pages. But I don't know what to do anymore.

```
import UIKit

class FilmsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var films = Films()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getDate()

    }

    func getDate() {
        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=world&apikey=eae75c46")!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                self.films = try JSONDecoder().decode(Films.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    func configureCell(cell: FilmsCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let search = self.films.search else { return }
        let films = search[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleFilmLabel.text = films.title
    }

}

extension FilmsViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

}

extension FilmsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let search = self.films.search else { return 0 }
        return search.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FilmsCell

        configureCell(cell: cell, for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've done a POC so far, getting data from an API and loading on screen.

For organization moving forward, you'll want to break this code up into multiple files.  Not to go overboard, I'd suggest starting with a API class that handles the details of creating http requests, things like header/body/auth.  It's up to you if API class returns data/json or film objects.  You'll also need a model class that handles keeping track of what page should be fetched next from server, via the api class.  you can keep the array of films here or in view controller.

As the user scrolls down you can either wait for them to reach the bottom, show an activity indicator below last cell while api fetch occurs, then insert the new results at the bottom, or you can pre-fetch data.

that should get you started at least.

Do the objects returned from the api have a id/date/order that can be used for future requests, like get items before.... Hopefully yes and you can use that and not track what page your on.